# ActionBarのmenuItemsクリックした時のDialogがすぐ落ちる

Tags: android

ListFragmentの次のページに、Actionbar Activityのクラスがあり、その中の 
ActionBarのmenuItemsクリックした時、あるボタンからDialogFragmentを表示させているのですが、すぐにDialogが閉じ、ListFragmentに戻ってしまいます。

Dialogをすぐに勝手に閉じないようにしたいのと、ListFragmentに遷移しないようにし、そのままActionbar Activity内に留めたいのですが、どのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか？

お知恵をお借り出来ますと幸いです。

ActionBarActivity クラス

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        //遷移先がフラグメントなので、FragmentTransactionで書く。
        case R.id.menu_home:
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, new Top());
            break;

        case R.id.menu_dialog:
            AlertDialogFragment alertDialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
            alertDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "AlertDialogFragment");
            break;
    }
    finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    }
```

DialogFragment

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("タイトル");
    builder.setMessage("メッセージ");
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok ,null);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
    return builder.create();
} }
```

Answer (score 3):

いろいろお困りだと思いますが、まずは作成しているアプリを一旦おやすみして、
Androidプログラミング入門用の本を１冊読み進めるのが、最終的に時間の短縮になると思います。
本を読み進めるなかで躓いて調べても分からなくなってしまったら、どんどん質問すべきだと思います。

さて、`ListFrament`に戻ってしまう件ですが、`onOptionsItemSelected`で`finish()`しています。
`finish()`を呼び出すと、`Activity`を閉じてしまいます。
`finish()`を削除すれば、希望の動作になると思います。

がんばってください。

Comment: yukiさん
いつも御丁寧に回答頂きましてありがとうございます。
非常に助かっております。頂いたアドバイスも参考にさせていただき、今週末は、基礎の理解に徹したいと思います。

`finish()`の削除をした所、逆にUPボタンや、`R.id.menu_home:`が効かなく(クリックできなく)なってしまいました。
これは、共存できないのでしょうか？

Comment: 上記のコードで動かない理由は分かりません。ブレークポイントを置いてデバッグして、`onOptionsItemSelected`に来るか確認してみてください。

Comment: ft.replace(R.id.container, new Top());の
containerが、別のActivity(Fragment)のものを使っていました。
これで正常に作動しました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`finish();`を呼んでいるのが原因な気がします